# Is it possible to change the position of a Farseer joint tie point?

Tags: c#, farseer-physics-engine

When I create a revolute joint in Farseer, then there is always a tie point in the center of each of the two bodies. Is it possible to change the position of a tie point?

For example:

I created a revolute joint but I want to change the tie point of the Windmillsail1 body. Is it possible to change the position of the point to the lower edge of the Windmillsail1 body? I marked the position of the lower edge with a red arrow.

[image: Tie point]

My code:

```
Body Windmillsail1, Windmillball;
RevoluteJoint RevJointA,
List<Vertices> list = new List<Vertices>();
Vector2 _origin;
float _scale;

uint[] data = new uint[WindmillsailSprite.Width * WindmillsailSprite.Height];
WindmillsailSprite.GetData(data);
Vertices textureVertices = PolygonTools.CreatePolygon(data, WindmillsailSprite.Width, false);
Vector2 centroid = -textureVertices.GetCentroid();
textureVertices.Translate(ref centroid);
_origin = -centroid;
textureVertices = SimplifyTools.ReduceByDistance(textureVertices, 4f);
list = Triangulate.ConvexPartition(textureVertices, TriangulationAlgorithm.Bayazit);
_scale = 1f;
Vector2 vertScale = new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(1)) * _scale;
foreach (Vertices vertices in list)
{
  vertices.Scale(ref vertScale);
}

Windmillsail1 = BodyFactory.CreateCompoundPolygon(world, list, 1.0f, BodyType.Dynamic);
Windmillsail1.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
Windmillsail1.Mass = 10;
Windmillsail1.IsSensor = true;
Windmillsail1.Position = new Vector2(1.45f, 4.05f);
Windmillsail1.Rotation = MathHelper.ToRadians(0);
Windmillsail1.CollisionCategories = Category.Cat10;

Windmillball = BodyFactory.CreateCircle(world, 0.25f, 1.0f);
Windmillball.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
Windmillball.Position = new Vector2(1.63f, 4.64f);

RevJointA = JointFactory.CreateRevoluteJoint(world, Windmillsail1, Windmillball, new Vector2(0f, 0f));
RevJointA.MotorSpeed = MathHelper.PiOver4;
RevJointA.MotorImpulse = 100;
RevJointA.MotorEnabled = true;
RevJointA.MaxMotorTorque = 100;

spriteBatch.Draw(WindmillsailSprite, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(this.Windmillsail1.Position), null, Color.White, this.Windmillsail1.Rotation, _origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Comment: Look at the arguments for `CreateRevoluteJoint`. Like... *really* look. Step into the Farseer source code and see what they do.

Comment: I tried to change the values(new Vector2(1f, 1.5f)) but it doesn't change the tie points: RevJointA = JointFactory.CreateRevoluteJoint(world, Windmillsail1, Windmillball, new Vector2(1f, 1.5f));